# DRV8256PEVM: Vref does not change Itrip

Tags: dc-motor, texas-instruments, motordriver

I'm playing with the TI's [DRV8256PEVM](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slou520d/slou520d.pdf) evaluation board based upon a [DRV8256P](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8256.pdf) driver.
The GUI connects to the board and I can enable the driver and change the IN1/2 PWM duty-cycle.

In the right pane I read AIFS = 0.5A.
[image]
I'm not sure what AIFS really means. A Google search with (DRV8256 AIFS) returns NO matches! And AIFS alone shows too much unrelated results.

I guess it is the Itrip, because when I measure a current on my power supply of 2x AIFS the driver rises the fault flag and disable the outputs.

The Itrip is set by the Vref slider (Vref = Itrip * 0.66) so a Vref of 3.3V should set Itrip at 5A. Anyway, changing the Vref slider does nothing about the actual Itrip.

I measured the Vref on the header and it reflects the actual position of the slider.

Am I missing anything?

### UPDATE

The datasheet says VrefA and VrefB should be tied together. Instead only VrefA follows the slider, while VrefA is stick to 970 mV.
So I removed R20 and R27 (0 ohm) and tied both Vref to 3.3V.

Surprisingly, the fault condition happens again when the average load on the power supply goes above 1A.

Furthermore, if I keep the current below 1A the motor spins, but the chip becomes so hot in a few seconds.

Comment: What does this mean: *evaluation board with mount a DRV8256P driver*? Also, when you say this: *a Vref of 3.3V should set Itrip at 5V* - do you actually mean 5 amps? It might mean amps, instantaneous, full-scale (for a guess).

Comment: DRV8256P is the model of the driver mounted on the DRV8256PEVM evaluation board. 5A: typo corrected!

Comment: It loosely scans as "with out a DRV..."

Comment: The DRV8256 datasheet lists Ifs as Peak output current (maybe FS = full scale?), so it does seem like that means the max current, though Itrip would make more sense like you said.